# How to Remove Table column names in Microsoft azure storage explorer tool?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to delete some unnecessary columns which are created but not using currently. Without deleting the table data or table in Microsoft azure storage explorer how can I delete columns manually?

Answer (score 4):

Spinning off of the answer from @frigon I performed the following steps:

1. Close the storage explorer
2. Delete \AppData\Roaming\StorageExplorer\Local Storage
3. Open storage explorer

It kept me logged in, kept all my settings, and only appears to have reset my account filters and table caches.

It looks like the caches are stored in leveldb in that folder, so you may be able to crack that open and find the specific value(s) to drop.

Answer (score 3):

Mildly annoying but you can fix the issue by deleting the entire contents of:

```
 AppData\Roaming\StorageExplorer
```

that will fix the issue.  You'll need to reauthorized the accounts but that's a mild inconvenience.  There's  likely a file or two within that directory that actually caches that data that is a more surgical approach but the few most obvious candidates didn't work for me so i just deleted the whole directory.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to delete columns for all entities in a table, since Azure Storage Table is a schema-less database. In other words, the entities within a table can have different properties respectively. You have to query all the entities, remove the useless properties from them one by one and then replace the modified entities back to the table.

Comment: ,Thanks for the response.But In my table we have around 80,000 rows we can't delete all the rows and replace/insert it again.FYI,the columns which I am looking to delete is not having any data.say for ex, I have total 6 columns among them 3 columns are having entities but 3 other columns are not having any data.So please tell me how to delete those 3 empty columns in azure table storage explorer tool.

Comment: My answer above applies to all the cases no matter if the property value is empty.

Comment: @PRAVEEN - I can't imagine the issue with 80,000 entity replacements, which is a very small amount of entities. That should be doable in like... a minute or two. And like Zhaoxing stated: there is no such "remove column" operation, as every entity is independent as far as properties go.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if you copy the table and paste it into a different storage account or simply rename the table then the new table will not reference the unused columns.   However, if you paste it back to the original location or rename the table back to the original name then the unused columns will still be shown, even if you delete the table first.

Strangely, if you create a brand new table with the same name it will only have the default columns.   But import the contents of the original table from file and the superfluous columns will also reappear even though there is no reference to those columns in the csv file.