# Schema-less but why then storage explorer displays properties of deleted entities?

Tags: azure-table-storage

I understand that Azure Storage Tables are schema-less but why then when looking at my tables using the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer I see columns displayed for properties that existing entities do not have populated (columns resulting from tests or that existed in deleted entities). Is this due to the caching done at the Storage Explorer level?

Adding a screenshot as suggested (but it really adds no value to the above description). Highlighted columns used in tests and deleted entities are still being displayed.
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include a screenshot of what you see in Storage Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a behavior specific to `Azure Storage Explorer` as you guessed.

By default empty property values are displayed as `null` here, however when you export the data or use it, the fields are not populated as `null` they are actually empty.

In this test, I added an entity with an additional property `gender` that is only present in that entity. We can see the rest entity records from earlier are also populated with `null` under the column.

But when you **Refresh** after the delete operation, those columns are cleared.

[image]

There seems to be a settings for rest *(blob, file share, managed disk)* to refresh views automatically after every operation.

[image]

Alternately you can view in the new **Storage browser (preview)** from the Azure portal to confirm on same.

[image]

I could not find any explanation or supporting documents for same. You can raise a support ticket or log a new issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new/choose) to get an official response.

Answer (score 2):

The refresh option wasn't working for me on Azure Storage Explorer version 1.27.1 with a ~10k row table, but I found another answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48870772/1874135

Spinning off of that answer I performed the following steps:

1. Close the storage explorer
2. Delete \AppData\Roaming\StorageExplorer\Local Storage
3. Open storage explorer

It kept me logged in, kept all my settings, and only appears to have reset my account filters and table caches (including dropping the cached-but-deleted columns).

It looks like the caches are stored in leveldb in that folder, so you may be able to crack that open and find the specific value(s) to drop.